# Error in Oracle 11g installation in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: oracle

While installing Oracle 11g in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,it showing error as Universal Installer can not run under root.

How can I solve this problem??Please help me.

Comment: Ubuntu is AFAIK not listed as supported OS by Oracle. Nevertheless, at least in the past (up to 10g) an installation was possible. Could you please quote the error you are getting?

Comment: @Izzy there are workarounds listed on the internet to install 11g onto Ubuntu, but they're lengthy and you have to modify everything, so...

Comment: @TheLordofTime They've never been short, not even the ones for RedHat (which *is* officially supported): from Kernel adjustments to package requirements, a lot of things to do...

Answer (score 0):

Oracle installer wants to run as oracle user. So as a pre-requisite you must create the appropriate user and group:

```
groupadd -g 50000 dba
groupadd -g 50001 oinstall
useradd -u 50000 -m -d /local/oracle -g oinstall -G dba oracle
```

(where `/local/oracle` is the home directory, you could also use `/home/oracle` instead). Having that done, you can `sudo su - oracle` and run the installer. Make sure all pre-requisites (kernel parameter, ulimits, etc.) are met (check with the Oracle documentation for that).

Still, the installer may refuse to do its job when detecting no supported OS. I don't know if any Debian-like system is supported; on Redhat derivates (e.g. CentOS) it worked to fake the `/etc/redhat-release` to reflect a supported system.